# Capture video using webcam in Java

Tags: java, javafx, webcam, video-capture

I am trying to capture video screenshot from a java application. I have donwloaded the **sarxos/webcam-capture** library. I have add to my project the executable jar. It is a little bit mess. I want to capture video from a simple javafx interface that I have created. The issue is that after installing the lib and slf4 then it required to install also xuggle. I add xuggle in the path and my code is the following:

```
File file = new File("output.ts");

IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(file.getName());
Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();

writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, size.width, size.height);

Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
webcam.setViewSize(size);
webcam.open(true);

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    System.out.println("Capture frame " + i);

    BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(webcam.getImage(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);

    IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000);
    frame.setKeyFrame(i == 0);
    frame.setQuality(0);

    writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);

    // 10 FPS
    Thread.sleep(100);
}

writer.close();

System.out.println("Video recorded in file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

However I am receiving the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-ferry in java.library.path
```

**EDIT2** I also tried the jxcapture library. I add in my project all the necessary libs I run the following code: [enter link description here](https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/jxcapture-support/samples/video/windows/capture-video-from-web-camera), the code worked fine I manage to store the video, however in the end I am receiving the following error:

> 8614 [JNIWrapper.ShutdownHook] ERROR com.jniwrapper.NativeResourceCollector - 
>   com.jniwrapper.FunctionExecutionException: Callback parameter types or their count are not correct
>       at com.jniwrapper.Function.invokeVirtualFunc(Native Method)

Any idea what this error is about?? What is JNIWrapper.ShutdownHook? I tried the code in 3 different machines and this is happened just to one of them? How can I handle this exception?

EDIT3: I tried @whitesite proposal EDIT3. The gui started and I have two buttons start and stop the start button opened the camera and when I tried to stop I received the following:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Pointer address of argument 0 is NULL.
>       at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_videoio$VideoWriter.write(Native Method)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameRecorder.record(OpenCVFrameRecorder.java:105)
>       at Test1.lambda$0(Test1.java:52)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: What do you mean by 'I add xuggle in the path'? As I understand it has its own dependencies and needs some precompiled binaries, which you must provide manually in case you don't use maven or something.

Comment: I add to my eclipse project webcam-capture then the xuggle_3.4 then the slf4j and bridj-0.6.2. I dont know what else should I add.

Comment: Basically, [`UnsatisfiedLinkError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) means that xuggle can't find required libs. If you read [xuggle download instructions](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads), you'd see that you need to provide all its dependencies and precompiled binaries. Using maven would be much easier.

Comment: Another thing is that I am not able to download updated version of the xuggle. I cant nowhere 5.2 or 5.4.

Comment: Seems they stopped supporting it long time ago. What are you trying to achieve? If you need just snapshots, it looks like plain sarxos webcam more than capable to do it. If you need more advanced video decoding/streaming/compressing features, than you might need some additional tool, maybe like ffmpeg.

Comment: I wanted to capture video from a simple interface that I have created. Indeed I am trying to find something that is easily imported in my code and not to use a external executable. However if I wont find anything this will be my case. If you have something else to recommend please do so.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing slf4-api-ver.jar in your classpath. However adding just the api will not be enough you will also need a provider like slf4j-simple-ver.jar. The latest available are version 1.7.21 and can be downloaded from here http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Comment: I donwloaded the zip file and I just add the slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar to my project. Still I got the same error :(!

Comment: Did you read this https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/114 ?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, that's what I got using this [JavaCV library](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) and their examples:

```
public class Test extends Application {

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    OpenCVFrameGrabber capture = OpenCVFrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
    capture.start();

    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
    Java2DFrameConverter javaConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

    VBox root = new VBox();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setHeight(capture.getImageHeight());
    canvas.setWidth(capture.getImageWidth());
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, capture.getImageWidth(), capture.getImageHeight());

    primaryStage.setTitle("Live video");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    Thread videoProcessor = new Thread(() -> {
        File output = new File("C:/Work/test.avi");
        OpenCVFrameRecorder recorder = new OpenCVFrameRecorder(output, capture.getImageWidth(), capture.getImageHeight());
        try {
            recorder.setVideoCodec(opencv_videoio.CV_FOURCC((byte) 'M', (byte) 'J', (byte) 'P', (byte) 'G'));
            recorder.start();
            while (true) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    break;
                }
                Frame frame = capture.grab();
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    BufferedImage image = javaConverter.getBufferedImage(frame, 1.0, false, null);
                    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().drawImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null),0,0);
                });
                recorder.record(frame);
            }
            recorder.stop();
            capture.release();
            recorder.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
        videoProcessor.interrupt();
    });

    videoProcessor.start();

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

It captures video from web cam and translates it live and in the same time writes to file. You need to include their library in classpath using maven or manual installation and also all the jars from binary zip archive. Maybe you don't need all of them, but I did't dig deep.
You can play with settings and investigate examples and sources. From what I've seen it's pretty powerful library.
**Edit**
Just video processing part:

```
Thread videoProcessor = new Thread(() -> {
        OpenCVFrameGrabber capture = null;
        FrameRecorder recorder = null;
        try {

            File output = new File("C:/Work/test2.avi");
            capture = OpenCVFrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
            capture.start();
            recorder = FrameRecorder.createDefault(output, capture.getImageWidth(), capture.getImageHeight());
            recorder.setFrameRate(8);
            recorder.setVideoCodec(opencv_videoio.CV_FOURCC((byte) 'M', (byte) 'J', (byte) 'P', (byte) 'G'));
            recorder.start();
            long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    break;
                }
                recorder.record(capture.grab());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                capture.release();
                recorder.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

You need to start process `videoProcessor.start()` somewhere and then interrupt it to stop recording `videoProcessor.interrupt()`. You might also need to set proper recorder frame rate to adjust it to your camera fps.
**Edit 2**
Code to output available devices:

```
int n = org.bytedeco.javacpp.videoInputLib.videoInput.listDevices();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " = " + org.bytedeco.javacpp.videoInputLib.videoInput.getDeviceName(i));
}
```

**Edit 3**
If webcam-capture works, than you can use it to capture images and use javaCV to record these images into videofile (pretty much like exapmle in youe question, just javaCV instead of xuggler). This is a small javafx app, which has two buttons: 'Start' starts the videoProcessing thread to capture video and 'Stop' interrupts this thread:

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_videoio;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Java2DFrameConverter;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameRecorder;


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class Test1 extends Application {

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    final double FPS = 25;
    final int WIDTH = 640;
    final int HEIGHT = 480;
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.setViewSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

    Java2DFrameConverter javaConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

    VBox root = new VBox();
    Button b1 = new Button("Start");
    Button b2 = new Button("Stop");

    root.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    Runnable r = () -> {
        File output = new File("C:/Work/test.avi");
        OpenCVFrameRecorder recorder = new OpenCVFrameRecorder(output, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        recorder.setFrameRate(FPS);
        try {
            recorder.setVideoCodec(opencv_videoio.CV_FOURCC((byte) 'M', (byte) 'J', (byte) 'P', (byte) 'G'));
            recorder.start();
            webcam.open();
            while (true) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    break;
                }
                BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
                recorder.record(javaConverter.getFrame(image));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / (long)FPS);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            webcam.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    b1.setOnAction(e->{
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        b2.setOnAction(e2->t.interrupt());
    });

    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: How can I capture just the video, I am little confused from all that code. I just want to store to my hard disk the video.

Comment: @JoseRamon Use just video processing part. See the edit.

Comment: I tried the code. When I have the code inside the thread does not work at all. If I just use the code without the thread my camera opens just for a frame and then is closing without the video to be store.

Comment: And after a while I am receiving the following message:org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: read() Error: Could not read frame in start().
 at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:211)

Comment: Seems like openCV can't read frame from your webcam Either it can not find the device or it is not supported. Try to run this from second edit to see the list and numbers of available devices.

Comment: @JoseRamon One more idea to try. It is not clear from question if sarxos/webcam-capture worked with your webcam (without xuggler, just grabbing snapshots), but if it did you can use it to grab snapshots instead of OpenCVFrameGrabber, and use openCV only to record the video from these snapshots.

Comment: The webcam-capture works fine with my webcam. My problems arise when I tried to to run the code for capturing videos.

Comment: @JoseRamon Ok, see Edit 3 for solution with webcam-capture with JavaCV

Comment: It doesnt work. Can you tell me what are the exact jar files that you add to the path??

Comment: I have just two dependencies in `pom.xml` for webcam capture lib as [here](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) and for JavaCV as [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv#downloads)

Comment: My prob is that I am not familiar with maven and the way to use pom.xml.

Comment: Can I add the dependencies without the use of Maven?

Comment: Well, there is [manual installation instructions](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv#manual-installation) for JavaCV as well. But Maven is not that scary. There is a lot of tutorials of how to install it and create simple project in whatever IDE you are using. It is just a build tool, which from other useful things, takes dependency management to itself. It creates directory structure for your project and `pom.xml` file with all necessary information about it and build process. There you put <dependency> tags for all required libs. Then you work with your java files as in usual project.

Comment: I installed everything manually. I got the gui running start and stop worked but with an exception. The camera opened close the file stored just once. I wasnt able to run it again.

Comment: @JoseRamon Can't say anything about manual installation. But after adding this two maven dependencies and javacv binaries, both versions (javaCV only and JavaCv + webcam-capture) worked for me pretty well without any problems, except maybe tweaking proper frame rate of video. So now I got a bunch of selfie videos:). Still I would suggest you to try maven approach. This way you'll be sure all dependencies are in place. Then you can post separate question describing specific exception you got.

Comment: Yes the thing is that I manage to capture the video but when I tried to re-capture it second time I got exceptions, so the installation seems to work.

Comment: @JoseRamon I guess I know what you are talking about. This app is just an example and does not recreate Thread object, which can not be started after it was stopped. Corrected the code a little. But still it's not very production ready, the main idea is just to show how capture frames and record them in video file.

Comment: I am able to right one time but in the second time I got the error java.lang.NullPointerException: Pointer address of argument 0 is NULL.