# Java multithreading issue: if I don't have the system.in.read() the capturer starts and stops immediately even without calling stop

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am trying to understand how exactly the threads works in java. I have a javafx project which is a simply game interface with questions and users. I am trying to capture the visual information of every game session using [jxcapture lib](https://www.teamdev.com/jxcapture). The thing is that I have to use multithreading since I cannot run both the gui and the capturer in the same time. I have a class which extends Thread which is the following:

**EDIT:**

```
    startTestButton = new Button("START");
    startTestButton.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (e) -> {


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

                  VideoCapture videoCapture = VideoCapture.create(VideoFormat.WMV);

                  List<VideoSource> availableVideoSources = VideoSource.getAvailable();
                  System.out.println("availableVideoSources = " + availableVideoSources);

                  if (availableVideoSources.isEmpty()) {
                      throw new IllegalStateException("No external video sources available");
                  }
                  VideoSource webCamera = availableVideoSources.get(0);
                  System.out.println("webCamera = " + webCamera);

                  videoCapture.setVideoSource(webCamera);

                  java.util.List<Codec> videoCodecs = videoCapture.getVideoCodecs();
                  System.out.println("videoCodecs = " + videoCodecs);
                  if (videoCodecs.isEmpty()) {
                      throw new IllegalStateException("No video codecs available");
                  }

                  Codec videoCodec = videoCodecs.get(2);
                  System.out.println("videoCodec = " + videoCodec);

                  EncodingParameters encodingParameters = new EncodingParameters(new File("file.wmv"));
                  encodingParameters.setBitrate(500000);
                  encodingParameters.setFramerate(10);
                  encodingParameters.setKeyFrameInterval(1);
                  encodingParameters.setCodec(videoCodec);

                  videoCapture.setEncodingParameters(encodingParameters);
                  videoCapture.start();

                  try {
                    System.in.read();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        });
```

My problem with the thread is that if I don't have the system.in.read() the capturer starts and stops immediately even without calling stop.

Comment: Have you looked at [`javafx.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)?

Comment: I try my approach using the javafx cocurrent.

Comment: When you extending Thread, you need to put you code in run() method, not start(). And if you do not need to alter Thread specific behavior, you better implement Runnable interface and use it to start new thread. Don't know about jxcapture, but I played a little with JavaCV library and webcam-capture, you can see some examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38282933/6540815)

Comment: Why do you need a thread? The [documentation](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxcapture/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxcapture/VideoCapture.html#start()) says that `start()` starts the capture *asynchronously* (i.e. the method exits immediately, with the capture presumably already running in another thread).

Comment: @whitesite I prefer the jxcapture since it seems a lighter solution and easier to understand and it seems to working. "James_D" it seems that the error is independent the multi-threading. Still I got the same issue with the System.in.read() without that line my capture start and stops immediately.

Comment: That's because without System.in your thread finish execution right after videoCapture.start(), because, as James_D mentioned, it is async, it does not wait or block execution. You need some logic to keep thread running.

Comment: How do you know the capture stops immediately? Without the blocking call (`System.in.read()`) the thread terminates immediately and you no longer have a reference to the `VideoCapture` object. If you don't have a reference to it, how are you determining that it stops? And you haven't explained why you need a thread at all, since the capture inherently runs asynchronously.

Comment: I check the video and the video is just 1 second (yes maybe you are right its not stopping exactly immediately).

Comment: I guess the bigger question is: when do you want it to stop?

Comment: The stop working fine, my only thing is to replace the read and keep the thread alive since i dont want to have a read in my interface.

Comment: What do you mean "the stop is working just fine". Nowhere in the code have posted do you call `videoCapture.stop()`. I don't understand the conditions under which you want it to stop - presumably it should stop as a response to some kind of user action. And you still haven't explained why you think you need to create a background thread.

Comment: I have two buttons in the one the recording is starting while in the other it stops. My prob is that without the System.in.read() the capturer stops before it reach the second button, while with the implementation with read for some reason the capturer works properly until the next button when the capturer should stop.

Comment: Presumably the `VideoCapture` is just written so that it stops if the object is garbage collected.

Comment: @James_D can you ellaborate a little bit for your last comment. I am not exactly sure that I understand it.

Comment: In your code, the reference `videoCapture` is scoped to the `run()` method, so once the `run()` method completes, is it out of scope. Since you can't possibly have any other references to the object `videoCapture` references (since it's created in that method), it becomes eligible for garbage collection as soon as `run()` completes, which, as previously explained, is basically immediately. A well-written video capture implementation will ensure that a capture stops under these circumstances (since there's no other possible way for it ever to be stopped).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use JXCapture, but according to the documentation, the `VideoCapture.start()` method starts the capture asynchronously. So there is no obvious reason to create your own background thread at all. Just start the capture with the start button and stop it with the stop button:

```
private VideoCapture videoCapture = null ;

private Button startTestButton ;
private Button stopTestButton ;

// ...
startTestButton = new Button("START");
startTestButton.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (e) -> {


    if (videoCapture == null) {

      videoCapture = VideoCapture.create(VideoFormat.WMV);

      List<VideoSource> availableVideoSources = VideoSource.getAvailable();
      System.out.println("availableVideoSources = " + availableVideoSources);

      if (availableVideoSources.isEmpty()) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("No external video sources available");
      }
      VideoSource webCamera = availableVideoSources.get(0);
      System.out.println("webCamera = " + webCamera);

      videoCapture.setVideoSource(webCamera);

      java.util.List<Codec> videoCodecs = videoCapture.getVideoCodecs();
      System.out.println("videoCodecs = " + videoCodecs);
      if (videoCodecs.isEmpty()) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("No video codecs available");
      }

      Codec videoCodec = videoCodecs.get(2);
      System.out.println("videoCodec = " + videoCodec);

      EncodingParameters encodingParameters = new EncodingParameters(new File("file.wmv"));
      encodingParameters.setBitrate(500000);
      encodingParameters.setFramerate(10);
      encodingParameters.setKeyFrameInterval(1);
      encodingParameters.setCodec(videoCodec);

      videoCapture.setEncodingParameters(encodingParameters);
      videoCapture.start();

      startTestButton.setDisable(true);
      stopTestButton.setDisable(false);

    } else {

      throw new IllegalStateException("Capture already in progress");
    }

});

stopTestButton = new Button("Stop");
stopTestButton.setDisable(true);

stopTestButton.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, e -> {
    if (videoCapture != null) {
        videoCapture.stop();
        videoCapture = null ;
        startTestButton.setDisable(false);
        stopTestButton.setDisable(true);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No capture in progress");
    }
});
```

Again, since I don't have access to this library, this is untested, however it should work.

Comment: If I put a thread.sleep its  working fine. However when I am trying to run the capturer again I got: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at com.teamdev.jxcapture.video.win.BaseDirectShowCapture.doStart(SourceFile:103)
 at com.teamdev.jxcapture.VideoCapture.start(SourceFile:146)

Comment: Does the stack trace show the actual cause of the exception?

Comment: It seems that the videoCapture.stop() doesnt stop the camera but  only the capturing stream. I am receiving a message: There is not enough recourses for the system, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at com.teamdev.jxcapture.video.win.BaseDirectShowCapture.doStart(SourceFile:103)
 at com.teamdev.jxcapture.VideoCapture.start(SourceFile:146)

Comment: COM object method returns error code: 0x800705AA; There are not enough resources from the system for the process